# XSLT 2.0 Group/Merging nodes based on matching elements

Tags: xml, xslt, merge, xslt-2.0

I'm new to XSLT and have been trying to merge nodes that match on a key (element). I tried some of the other solutions but not getting my head around it correctly on my dataset.

Input:

```
<coll>
  <rootNode>
     <Header>
        <code> 1234 </code> <-- key to match on
        <name> Name1 </name>
     </Header>
     <node2> Any text </node2>
     <node4> Any data here </node4>
     <children>
        <childID> 3456 </childID>
        <type> Child </type>
     </children>
  </rootNode>
  <rootNode>
     <Header>
       <code> 1234 </code>
       <name> Name1 </name> 
     </Header>
     <node2> Different Text </node2>
     <node4> Different data here </node4>
     <children>
        <childID> 789 </childID>
        <type> Parent </type>
     </children>
  </rootNode>
</coll>
```

Expected output:

```
<coll>
  <rootNode>
     <Header>
        <code> 1234 </code>
        <name> Name1 </name>
     </Header>
     <node2> Any text </node2>
     <node4> Any data here </node4>
     <node2> Different Text </node2>
     <node4> Different data here </node4>
     <children>
        <childID> 3456 </childID>
        <type> Child </type>
        <childID> 789 </childID>
        <type> Parent </type>
     </children>
  </rootNode>
</coll>
```

I.e. match on Header/code value, and then merge where *any* subnode has different value.  Therefore any nodes that have identical value do not duplicate.

Hope this makes sense, my first SO post, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs functx">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:function name="functx:index-of-node" as="xs:integer*">
  <xsl:param name="nodes" as="node()*"/>
  <xsl:param name="nodeToFind" as="node()"/>

  <xsl:sequence select="
  for $seq in (1 to count($nodes))
  return $seq[$nodes[$seq] is $nodeToFind]
 "/>

</xsl:function>

<xsl:function name="mf:eliminate-deep-equal-duplicates" as="node()*">
  <xsl:param name="nodes"/>
  <xsl:sequence
    select="for $node in $nodes
            return $node[not(some $preceding-node in $nodes[position() lt functx:index-of-node($nodes, $node)] satisfies deep-equal($node, $preceding-node))]"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="coll">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="rootNode" group-by="Header/code">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Header,
                                     mf:eliminate-deep-equal-duplicates(current-group()/(* except (Header, children))),
                                     children"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="rootNode/children">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="mf:eliminate-deep-equal-duplicates(current-group()/children/*)"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As for an explanation: The posted stylesheet has three templates, the first being the identity transformation template (that allows us the copy the elements we want to copy by doing `apply-templates` on them in other templates), the second matching `coll` elements to create a shallow copy of them and then apply text book `for-each-group` on the the `rootNode` elements, grouping them by `Header/code`, as you asked for. Inside the `for-each-group`, for each group an `xsl:copy` creates a `rootNode` and populates it by processing the `Header` element of the first item in the group (so we get only one `Header` result element in each group), the children except `Header` and `children` of each item in the group where there is no previous `deep-equals` element in the group and the `children` element of the first item in the group, to be able to ensure each group gets a `children` child element. In the template for that element we need then to make sure that we process all grand children in the current group that have no `deep-equal` duplicate before them.

I have refactored the long expression into a function `mf:eliminate-deep-equal-duplicates`, it selects those nodes in a sequence of nodes for which no preceding node in the same sequence is `deep-equal`.

The solution makes use of the function http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_index-of-node.html of the functx library which gives us the index of a node in a sequence.

As Vladimir Nesterovsky has pointed out in a comment, the function `mf:eliminate-deep-equal-duplicates` could also be implemented without using the functx `functx:index-of-node`:

```
<xsl:function name="mf:eliminate-deep-equal-duplicates" as="node()*">
  <xsl:param name="nodes"/>
  <xsl:sequence
    select="for $i in (1 to count($nodes)),
            $node in $nodes[$i]
            return $node[not(some $preceding-node in $nodes[position() lt $i] satisfies deep-equal($node, $preceding-node))]"/>
</xsl:function>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'm not sure why we need the second template match?  Could you explain to two key apply-template lines as I'm having trouble following how they work?

Comment: I have edited the answer with a corrected version and some explanation. It turned out the previous suggestion had the right approach but not quite the right implementation I think. I have tested with some sample data that has duplicate elements and the new solution eliminates them.

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot Martin, explanation helps a lot

Comment: I would rewrite body in mf:eliminate-deep-equal-duplicates as

  <xsl:sequence
    select="for $i in (1 to count($nodes)), $node in $nodes[$i]
            return $node[not(some $preceding-node in $nodes[position() lt $i] satisfies deep-equal($node, $preceding-node))]"/>

Comment: @VladimirNesterovsky, thanks for the suggestion, I see it eliminates the need for using the `functx:index-of-node` from the functx function library and makes for a more compact expression. I will add your suggestion to the answer.